# Not working maxlengthurl(too longer) in any browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am looking for new wcf rest web service in asp.net 4.0 using vs2010.
here is my code for passing                                                  url:

```
"homewizard/Service1.svc/monthlytips/country_state=US_IL_N/tip_code=NoInformation/feature=ACC,FAHD,WHG,FP,WA,DY,DWSH,GD,REF,STV,OVN,MW,CPTR,ATT,ROOF,RG,BSMT,FDN,SPX,GAR,EGF,PLB,DOOR,WIND,WS,LWN,DKG,PF,BBQ,WSD,OWF,DWY,OLIT,HL,SPTC,CF,WF,CPTS,DVB,FURW,FURL,FURU,MAT,BATH,KITC,CLST,LITE,SD,COD,FE,EMS,PC,SS,MED,EAUD,ENR,GARR,INR,MGR,TAXR,TELR,CGD,DOOR,WIND,WS/dwelling_type=1/tip_priority=1/month=3/tip_knowledge_level=1/tipbr_ensav=0/tipbr_safe=0/tipbr_avoid=1/tipbr_comfort=1/tipbr_value=1/tipbr_appear=1/tipbr_green=0/tipbr_money=0/tipbr_space=1/tipbr_allergy=2/tipbr_elderly=2/tipbr_children=2/tip_location_temp=0/tip_location_humidity=0"
```

**output:Bad Request - Invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.**

my web config is: httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024"

but it's working my local host not in server pc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need an URL like that? Can't you pass your parameters in another way?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your issue is that that's not a restfull URL, the url should just be the location of the resource you are dealing with, the body of the request should contain the details of the request (as xml or json for example). It will both solve your problem and result in less code to manage the parameters via deserialization into a request object server side, not to mention clear up that url.

***UPDATE***

Are you sure thats a GET and not a PUT, what is the call meant to do?

If it is a GET I'd do something like the following...

**Service Interface**

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "monthlytips")]
AppropriateReturnType MonthlyTips(MonthlyTip monthlytip);
```

**DTO Object**

```
public class MonthlyTip 
{
    public string CountryState { get; set; }
    public string TipCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Feature { get; set; }
    public int DwellingType { get; set; }
    public int TipPriority { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Thats off the top of my head so it might need a little refining and you'll need to implement the interface, finish the DTO and so on but that's the approach you should take.

Comment: here is my code as you request.
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "monthlytips/country_state={country_state};